# DB2 query execution performance issue

Tags: sql, db2

We have one application in that we have 3 table in DB2 schema. I am using below query to fetch record. the transaction table may contain more than 1000000 records. I wrote below query to fetch data from multiple tables but it is taking more time than expectation of testers.

`select * from (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( order by SOURCE_REFERENCE_NO,Trans_Date,Trans_Time,User_ID ) as RN ,Trans_Type from transaction t left join applicationref ar on t.code = ar.code 
left join user u on u.username = t.useraccess left join user u1 on u1.username = t.username
)as w`

Comment: Did you mean to post some logic?

Comment: Yes, For example Add Employee, Edit Employee, Delete Employee.

Comment: Please, remove my question from duplicate. It is not duplicate now. I am in trouble. Please urgnet help needed.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can declare additional methods in your Servlet, but ideally you should encapsulate those business logic into Services and DAO (Data Access Object) as separate classes.

Comment: Yes that's true. I have to bind different method with different business logic .Can you give little bit more explanation? How to bind multiple action with single servlet.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to **Ish's** answer.

Yes, you should define the actual business login in a separate service class or DAO but the actual call of this different business logic should be appropriately called in the Servlet itself.

The scheme that suits your requirement is creating a hidden action parameter in the form. Lets call it `action`.  Check for this parameter in Servlet doGet or doPost method.

You can either use 'switch statement' if Java 1.8 or 'if else if' for any other version.

Something like this.

```
String action = request.getParameter('action');
if(action.equals('logic1')){
    service.businesslogic2();
} else if(action.equals('logic2')){
    service.businesslogic2();
} else if(action.equals('logic3'))
....
....
....
```

service is any service class instance.

Comment: Yes, But what is more preferable in development with code quality.               1) With Single Servlet                                                                            2) Seperate servlet for multiple operation

Comment: we can use same servlet for very closely related actions.